# Finding the set of values of k for which a modulus equation has exactly 4 roots

Tags: inequality, problem-solving, absolute-value

In my assignment, I have the following question:

> Find the set of values of k for which the equation $|x^2-1|+x=k$ has
> exactly four roots.

What I've tried:

Removed the modulus and made two different equations $x^2+x-(k+1)=0$ and $x^2-x+(k-1)=0$. Calculated their discriminants such that $D_{1}$ and $D_{2}$ (the discriminants of the first and second equations, respectively) are both positive, I got $k∈(-5/4,5/4)$. After that, since in the first equation $x∈(-∞, -1]∪[1,∞)$, I used the quadratic formula and got $±√D_{1}∈(-∞,-1]∪[3,∞)$ and proceeding similarly for the second equation, I got $±√D_{2}∈(-1,3)$. I am not able to proceed any further, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two conditions should rather be
$$±√D_{1}∈(-∞,-1)∪(3,∞)$$
$$±√D_{2}∈(-1,3)$$
(to prevent $x^2-1$ from being equal to $0$).
The first one means
$$-√D_{1}∈(-∞,-1),\quad+√D_{1}∈(3,∞)$$
i.e. $$√D_{1}∈(1,∞)\cap(3,∞),$$i.e.
$D_1>9,$ i.e. $k>1.$ Similarly, the second one means $D_2<1,$
i.e. again $k>1.$

Conclusion: the set of values of $k$ for which $|x^2-1|+x=k$ has exactly four solutions is $(1,5/4).$

Another method was to [plot $y=|x^2-1|+x$](https://www.google.com/search?q=x%2Babs(x%5E2-1)) and see which horizontal lines cut the curve four times.

Comment: Many MathSE responders would have opted for your concise answer, rather than my long-winded answer.  However, I think that if the assumption is made that $x^2 - 1$ mut not equal $0$, without in depth analysis, then a Math student new to the topic is not going to clearly understand why such an assumption is valid.  I agree that you graphically/visually covered the situation.  However, I think that (instead) a complete analytical approach is required, no matter how long-winded the answer is.  ... Food for thought going forward, for your subsequent answers.

Comment: @CallousCalculus is my complete analytical approach (following and completing yours) sufficient for you? Don't you find it obvious that $x^2-1$ cannot be $0$ if we want $4$ solutions? I am ready to add details if needed. And did you enjoy my additional graphic solution?

Answer (score 0):

> Find the set of values of k for which the equation $|x^2-1|+x=k$ has  exactly four roots.

> What I've tried:

> Removed the modulus and made two different equations $x^2+x-(k+1)=0$ and $x^2-x+(k-1)=0$.

You have two cases

- $(x^2 - 1) \leq 0.$
- $(x^2 - 1) \geq 0.$

Note the overlap in the two cases, where $~x^2 - 1 = 0.~$  This overlap will be discussed following the discussion of the two individual cases.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1} ~: x^2 - 1 \leq 0}$

Any roots of $x$ must be in the region $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ 
and the pertinent equation is 
$1 - x^2 + x = k \implies x^2 - x + (k-1) = 0 \implies $

$$x = \frac{1}{2} \left[1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 4(k-1)}~\right]
~=~ \frac{1}{2} \left[1 \pm \sqrt{5 - 4k}~\right]. \tag1 $$

To complete Case 1, you have to find all values of $k$ such that:

- $5 - 4k > 0$
- The corresponding roots represented in (1) above are **both** in the range $-1 \leq x \leq 1.$

For the moment, let $A$ denote $\sqrt{5 - 4k} \implies A > 0$.

Then, the two roots will be given by

$$\frac{1 + A}{2}, ~~\text{and}~~ \frac{1 - A}{2}. \tag2 $$

So, it is clear that both of the roots represented by (2) above will be in the range $~-1 \leq x \leq 1,~$ if and only if $A \leq 1.$

Therefore, you have that

$$0 < \sqrt{5 - 4k} \leq 1 \implies $$

$$0 < (5 - 4k) \leq 1 \implies 1 \leq k < \frac{5}{4}.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2} ~: x^2 - 1 \geq 0}$

Any roots of $x$ must be in the region 
$x \leq -1~$ or $~x \geq 1$ 
and the pertinent equation is 
$x^2 - 1 + x = k \implies x^2 + x - (k+1) = 0 \implies $

$$x = \frac{1}{2} \left[-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4(k+1)}~\right]
~=~ \frac{1}{2} \left[-1 \pm \sqrt{5 + 4k}~\right]. \tag3 $$

To complete Case 2, you have to find all values of $k$ such that:

- $5 + 4k > 0$
- The corresponding roots represented in (3) above are **both** in the range $~x \leq -1~$ or $~x \geq 1.$

For the moment, let $A$ denote $\sqrt{5 + 4k} \implies A > 0$.

Then, the two roots will be given by

$$\frac{-1 + A}{2}, ~~\text{and}~~ \frac{-1 - A}{2}. \tag4 $$

So, it is clear that both of the roots represented by (4) above will be in the range  $~x \leq -1~$ or $~x \geq 1 ~$ if and only if $A \geq 3.$

Therefore, you have that

$$\sqrt{5 + 4k} \geq 3 \implies 5 + 4k \geq 9 \implies k \geq 1.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Analysis}}$

This portion of my response is intentionally going to be **very slow and pedantic**, because the target audience is Math students new to the topic.  For a more sophisticated audience, this response would have been significantly shorter.

The results so far are:

- The combined assumption that $1 \leq k <  \dfrac{5}{4}$ 
  and $(x^2 - 1) \leq 0$, will yield two distinct roots that both satisfy $~(x^2 - 1) \leq 0.$
- The combined assumption that $1 \leq k $ 
  and $(x^2 - 1) \geq 0$, will yield two distinct roots that both satisfy $~(x^2 - 1) \geq 0.$

So, **superficially**, you could **wrongly** infer that the correct answer is $1 \leq k < \frac{5}{4}.$  In order to get the correct answer, you have to consider the original question more carefully.

It is required to identify all values of $k$ that result in **four distinct roots**.  Case 1 identified a range for $k$ that would provide **two distinct roots** that satisfied $(x^2 - 1) \leq 0.$  Case 2 identified a range for $k$ that would provide **two distinct roots** that satisfied $(x^2 - 1) \geq 0.$

In order to complete this (**very tricky**) problem, you have to consider which values of $k$ will result in **four distinct roots** from Case 1 and Case 2 combined.

This will be done by:

- Changing the Case 1 specification to force $~(x^2 - 1) < 0,~$ and changing the Case 2 specification to force $~(x^2 - 1) > 0.$
- These changes will guarantee **four distinct roots**.
- Then, consider Case 1 and Case 2 separately.  In each case, **manually** identify what happens if a value of $k$ is permitted that results in at least one of the roots specifically satisfying $x^2 - 1 = 0.$

In Case 1, if the requirement had (instead) been that $(x^2 - 1) < 0$, then the resulting range would have been

$$1 < k < \frac{5}{4}.$$

In Case 2, if the requirement had (instead) been that $(x^2 - 1) > 0$, then the resulting range would have been

$$1 < k.$$

Therefore, before deciding on a final answer, it remains to consider exactly what happens when $k = 1.$

Consider the equation

$$|x^2 - 1| + x = 1.$$

If the Case 1 assumption is made that $x^2 - 1 \leq 0$, then the two roots are $0$ and $1$.

If the Case 2 assumption is made that $x^2 - 1 \geq 0$, then the two roots are $-2$ and $1$.

So, the specific value of $k = 1$ generates only **three** distinct roots, rather than four.

Therefore, the final answer is

$$1 < k < \frac{5}{4}.$$

Comment: The only thing I don't understand here is that why, in case 2, will the roots lie in the given interval iff $5+4k>9$, why not if $5+4k>1$?

Comment: @CallousCalculus Look at the expression in (4): $$\frac{-1 + A}{2}, ~~\text{and}~~ \frac{-1 - A}{2}.$$  This places two constraints on $A$.  You need $~\dfrac{-1 + A}{2} \geq 1 \implies A \geq 3,~$ and you also need $~\dfrac{-1 - A}{2} \leq -1 \implies A \geq 1.$  Since both constraints must be satisfied, you need $A \geq 3.$  Therefore, you must have $$\sqrt{5 + 4k} \geq 3 \implies 5 + 4k \geq 9 \implies k \geq 1.$$

Comment: @CallousCalculus Note further that at the end of my response, when I alter the Case 2 constraint so that $~(x^2 - 1) > 1,~$ rather than $~(x^2 - 1) \geq 1.~$ that the effect is that you must have $$\sqrt{5 + 4k} > 3 \implies k > 1.$$

Comment: You mention at the end that if $x=1$, the equation will have three roots. How would one arrive at this conclusion independently of anything done in this question. I suppose you would take A in one equation such that it is equal to zero and in the other such that it is greater than zero, and vice versa in the second case.

Comment: @CallousCalculus No, if $~\color{red}{k} = 1,~$ then the equation will have three roots.  The whole point of my (**very long-winded**) answer, is that it takes a very sophisticated intuition to confidently see this and prove it immediately.  My own intuition falls short of any more elegant approach to investigating what happens when $k=1.$  I think that it is a **bad idea** for the (**fairly new**) Math student to look for elegant shortcuts, to this problem.

Comment: I asked because I have actually 4 such problems in my assignment, asking me to find k such that the equation has only one/two/three/four roots. I was wondering whether thing method of using the discriminant would be valid in the other three. It doesn't appear to work for the one solution question, and it only works partially for the two solutions question. For the two solutions question, it got me to $(5/4, ∞)$ but the final answer also has $∪(-1,1)$.

Comment: @CallousCalculus I am not sure what you are saying.  To the best of my knowledge, the **generic** procedure that I provided allows you to identify all values of $k$ that will yield $4$ distinct roots, which is what your original posting was asking.  So, avoiding any shortcuts, you can use this answer as a model to find the associated values of $k$ that yield $4$ distinct roots, for any similar problem. ...see next comment.

Comment: @CallousCalculus The first issue is: does this generic procedure **make sense** to you.  If not, please post a comment, following my answer, explaining where you are unsure of the validity of the approach.  ...see next comment

Comment: @CallousCalculus Assuming that validity is not in dispute, try to follow this exact procedure for one of the other problems, keeping in mind that you are merely trying to identify those values of $k$ that yield $4$ distinct roots.  If you run into a problem, then **create a separate MathSE posting**, have the separate posting provide a link to this posting, for reference, and **very clearly** show all of your work.  Then, I (or someone) will resolve the issue in the separate posting.  ...see next comment

Comment: @CallousCalculus Assuming that you then conquer the roadblock of being able to identify all values of $k$ that generate $4$ distinct roots, for any such generic problem, then try to analyze, for a generic problem, which values of $k$ instead generate $1, 2, $ or $3$ solutions, instead of $4$ solutions.   ...see next comment

Comment: @CallousCalculus If you run into a problem with this last hurdle, after carefully studying my answer, then (again) create a new MathSE posting that focuses on finding the values of $k$ that generate $1,2,$ or $3$ distinct roots, rather than $4$.  Again, you will want the separate posting to provide a link to this posting, and you will want to very carefully show all of your work in the separate posting.

Comment: I have no doubts whatsoever about the validity of this approach for this problem, thanks.