# Finding $k$ such that a modulus equation has one root

Tags: problem-solving, absolute-value

In addition to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590397/finding-the-set-of-values-of-k-for-which-a-modulus-equation-has-exactly-4-roots), I have a similar problem in my assignment asking me to find k such that $|x^2-1|+x=k$ has only one root. Proceeding similarly , I

> Removed the modulus and made two different equations $x^2+x−(k+1)=0$ and $x^2−x+(k−1)=0$.

After this, I took $D_1>0$ and $D_2<0$ in the first case and $D_1<0$ and $D_2>0$ in the second. In the first case, I got $k=-5/4$ and $k>5/4$ and in the second case I got $k=5/4$ and $k<-5/4$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: just graph the thing. First do $y=x^2,$   then do $y = x^2 - 1. $   Next $y = |x^2 -1 |  $  and finally $y = |x^2 - 1|   + x.$  The process will teach you something. Should be enough to plot $x$   integers,  say $-3 \leq x \leq 2$  and maybe $x = \frac{n}{2}$ for odd integer $n$

Comment: Doing the drawings will also show you your previous question.   With, you see, less chance of error than algebra on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient method to solve this would be to draw the graphs of the function and then, by trial and error, see which value (or range of values) of $k$ satisfy the condition. For different values of k, the graph will intersect the x-axis at different points, the key is to *see* what values of k would satisfy the condition.